Sink drainpiece not lined up with P-trap
New DIYer here. Was changing out the old bathroom sink drain and found that the previous owner's installation has the current drain being pulled due to misalignment with the p-trap.

What would be recommended here? From the initial look, I was thinking of shortening the L shaped pipe coming from the wall side.

The picture link will not work.

Welcome! This question might be similar to yours - does the answer there help?

Edited with just link. @Greg This is super helpful! I think from that post, it means best strategy would be make the outlet pipe shorter and rotate until perfectly aligned?

Yes that's the idea. You see how the P trap points away from the wall inlet now? It might be necessary to flip the P around so that it points toward the wall inlet. If everything is too crowded and that's not possible, but the horizontal L pipe entry angle into the elbow just isn't right, you might have to extend straight out of the wall inlet, then use a 90 degree elbow, and connect the L pipe to this.

You should be able to rotate the trap some so that the tailpiece drain is vertical, but the horizontal piece may be too long.

@Greg Hill As I feared, it seems the current set-up is just too crowded to be able to adjust through rotation. I'm also not ready to change out the wall inlet elbow as I don't currently have the tools (glued down and seems to be a bigger change) unless absolutely needed. After some adjustments, I think I found a solution with the current space by using another 45 degree elbow and extending it outside towards the door to be able to complete the P-trap. Is there any issues I should consider with this proposed setup? https://imgur.com/a/tXh6pyg

Yes the additional 45 elbow looks like a fine way of solving the problem.

cut the horizontal arm shorter and rotate the "J" piece so that it points towards the wall connection more, and is just offset enough to line up with the horizontal piece.

Loosen nuts A, B, C, D.   Note that all 4 of them can rotate when loose, and A, B, D can slip in and out.
First-time-DIY extra step: Take them apart and note that A,B, and D all have cone-shaped washers where the nut forces the pointy end into the larger fitting, while C has a flat washer and a flange.  It's easy to see how the different joints all work, and this will help you a lot.
With everything assembled but loose, do your best to make things fit by rotating and slipping all the joints as needed.  In your case it won't happen because the pipe with the red arrow is too long, and  Part D, which allows it to slip in and out, doesn't have that much play.
Shove it all the way in, estimate how much you need to cut off, and cut it off with a hacksaw (or if it's soft enough, a knife).  Be conservative, you can cut off more if you have to.
Once everything fits comfortably and straight, tighten everything 90%, straighten everything again, then tighten everything fully.  Hand-tight might be good enough, or you can add a quarter turn with a wrench.  You can easily destroy these fittings by overtightening with a wrench so be careful.

Note the metal tail piece of the sink is in two parts.  Where they join is a bit of a mess.  If you want some extra fun, you could replace the lower of the two pieces with a longer one, install it more cleanly, and eliminate part A which is just an extension piece.
Where to cut?   If you draw a straight line out from the trap adapter and you rotate C in a circle around B, the line and circle will meet in 0, 1, or 2 places.  If it's 0 you need another piece or to change the angle of the trap adapter at the wall so it points more towards the tail.  If it's 1 or 2 you have to cut the pipe to put joint C at one of those junctions.   In your new configuration it looks like you cut it too much.


Thanks for this! Was super helpful and got really far. I went ahead and trimmed down the horizontal piece but its still not enough to align it. I think i've trimmed the max length due to the piece curvature now bumping into the outlet. I've come to understand why they did what they did. Anything i can do to remedy this? https://imgur.com/a/6guYiNG

I added to the answer

Using the swivel test as you suggested, there's no points where the trap adapter/outlet pipe really aligns cleanly with the p-trap:  (1) First alignment would be as seen in the initial image where everything is being forced together and causing misalignment as the connector piece comes into contact with the L pipe.
(2) Second alignment is not possible as it comes in contact with the adapter itself. So in that case, it leaves updating the trap adapter but it seems to be a piece that is currently glued onto the outlet pipe and not too confident in changing that unless absolutely needed.

Current thought process is to either get another elbow to connect to the current outlet elbow to give me another angle of attack, or maybe going with a 1.25in p-trap and see if the reduction in size helps?
